# Character encoding when executing SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

Have been searching for a while but can't find the answer. This is [my test page](http://www.andersbjarnle.se/ta_bort2/) based on [this tutorial](http://hycus.com/2011/03/16/load-more-like-facebook-or-old-twitter-using-php-mysql-jquery/). The first 5 posts from my database are printed just fine, but when loading another 5 the encoding messes up with the "å", "ä" and "ö" characters. If you for some reason can't see it the standard � character replaces the special ones.

Would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: `loadmore.php` doesn't specify which charset its content is in. It's in latin1, but the default guess in your browser is UTF-8, so the text gets mangled. Your test page specifies its charset as latin1, that's why it works. If you're specifying the charset manually in the test page, you'll have to do it manually in `loadmore.php` as well. If not, then there's something that's different between the test page and `loadmore.php`. Also, you should use UTF-8 instead of latin1 anyway, since the articles you show could contain non-latin1 characters.

Comment: The [PHP FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) recommends http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html

Comment: @MikeB, [this section](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html#why-do-i-have-such-strange-characters-on-my-website) is especially relevant in this case.

Comment: @Mike B Thanks a lot! I used the utf8_encode and it worked!